# Can we make a calculator in php with number buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I made a calculator program with number buttons and one textbox in javascript.
But I've been told to use php for the logical part.
Is it possible to input multiple values and displaying the result in the same textbox, by using php ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please show some effort and code

Comment: Ajax and Php will help you out.

Comment: We  = Can't. You = Can

Comment: yes of course you can do it

Comment: if you tried something, probably you shouldn't have asked here

Comment: I don't see why not , you'll need ajax thou .

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, yes it can be done. If you insist on using PHP then I would advise the use of Ajax to allow you to post your requests to your PHP server without the user's browser window navigating away or refreshing, to provide a coherent user experience.

However, why would you like to do the calculation logic server-side? If you are making a simple calculator, Javascript is more than capable of providing the functionality you need without the costly requests to the server, and the logic will be much simpler as a result.